# compare two files using awk

Tags: arrays, unix, awk

PFB the scenario

I have two files

file 1

```
val1
val2
val3
```

file 2

```
val1
val2
val4
```

the below code would give me all matching rows

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$1];next}$1 in arr{print $1,"in both files"} file1 file2
```

the output would be

```
 val1 in both files
 val2 in both files
```

But what I wanted is

```
val4
```

how can I change the code so that I can get the value which are **NOT PRESENT in the array arr.**

Comment: Oh come on, in any Algol-based language (C, C++, Pascal, Ada, Java, Shell, Pyhon, Perl, Awk, etc., etc.) how to you negate a condition? You stick a `!` in front of it. So just do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `!` operator to print the values in file2 but not in file1.

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2`

I tried it and output is :

```
$ cat file1              
val2
val3
$ cat file2               
val1
val2
val4
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2
val4
```